# html5 drag/drop determine source of dragged item

Tags: javascript, html

If I drag a file onto a webpage it fires the dragenter event.  If I drag an  element it also fires the same event.  How might I determine if the dragged item is coming from html or from an external app like explorer.

Thanks.

Comment: I got this issue once, not sure if you can know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing the drag and drop from html, you would do

```
e.dataTransfer.setData() //at the source
```

and

```
e.dataTransfer.getData() //at the destination
```

If you are getting items from explorer, you would do

```
var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
```

So I think you would know, where it is coming from.

Comment: chrome didnt have anything in files either way, but i was able to check dataTransfer.types for text/html and that did what i needed. Thanks